# Why are the values in my inner object blank?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, javascript-objects

I am just trying to get a JSON output like this

```
{
"SW Reqs or Problem Analysis & Estimate": {
    "Estimate_Days": "I",
    "Performers": "am",
    "Percent_Done": "so",
    "Work_Done": "frustrated",
    "Remaining_Work": "this",
    "Comments": "won't"
},
"SW Requirements Doc ( in DOORS)": {
    "Estimate_Days": "WORK",
    "Performers": "PLEASE",
    "Percent_Done": "HELP",
    "Work_Done": "AAHHHHH",
    "Remaining_Work": "HHHHHH",
    "Comments": "HHHHHH!!!!"
}, ...etc
```

but my json looks like this

```
{
"SW Reqs or Problem Analysis & Estimate": {
    "Estimate_Days": "",
    "Performers": "",
    "Percent_Done": "",
    "Work_Done": "",
    "Remaining_Work": "",
    "Comments": ""
},
"SW Requirements Doc ( in DOORS)": {
    "Estimate_Days": "",
    "Performers": "",
    "Percent_Done": "",
    "Work_Done": "",
    "Remaining_Work": "",
    "Comments": ""
},...etc
```

here's my script,

```
$('#test').click(function(){
    var content = {};
    var inner = {};
    $('.Data').each(function() {

        var row = $(this).siblings(":first").text();
        var id = $(this).attr('id').split('~');
        var blah = id[0];
        var html = $(this).html();
        content[row] = inner;
        inner[blah] = html;
    });
    var hey = JSON.stringify(content);
    console.log(hey);
});
```

it iterates through `<td>`s in a table. If I test just 
`console.log(html)` or `console.log(inner[blah])` it outputs the data I need from the `<td>`s but for some reason it displays them as blank when I put it I try to output `content`.

Is the problem with this line?

```
content[row] = inner;
inner[blah] = html;
```

Is that the proper way to create an object, `content`, with key, `row`, with values as another object named `inner` that has keys `blah` and values of `html`? This shouldn't be this hard. I have to be missing something. I read that you might as well use JSON when you have multidimensional objects, but I can't figure out why the strings after "Estimate_Days" and such are blank. PLEASE HELP.

EDIT: Here's a couple lines of the php loop that generates the html:

```
foreach($group_results as $group){
    echo '<tr><td class="Row_Title'.$group['Group_ID'].'">'.$group['Group_Name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td class="Data" contenteditable="true" name="Estimate_Days~'.$group['Group_ID'].'" id="Estimate_Days~'.$group['Group_ID'].'"></td>';
    echo '<td class="Data" contenteditable="true" name="Performers~'.$group['Group_ID'].'" id="Performers~'.$group['Group_ID'].'"></td>'; ...etc
```

Comment: put you all html js code in https://jsfiddle.net/ (and menu>Save and give us link)

Comment: i'll just update my question and post everything in there, theres some php on there that I can't really reproduce in a fiddle

Comment: Would be good to see the HTML, if only a static example with a couple of rows.

Comment: Possible problem:  all of the values of `content` point to the same singular `inner` object.

Comment: @stephen.vakil hmm so should I instantiate the inner object somewhere else? Like maybe do a second loop? like instantiate `content`, start a loop through each `<tr>`, instantiate `inner` in there, and then populate it with values from the loop through the `<td>`s, then add that into the `content` object and repeat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**:  Note that your `td` content seems to be empty in your posted loop code.  Most likely that was why everything was blank, but it was masking the additional issues with object references.

As I mentioned, you are re-using the same instance of `inner` each time.  What you really want to do is find each `Row_Title` cell and then for each of those, fill a row with the remaining siblings.  I suggest the following javascript (with some sample HTML to demonstrate).  This loops through each "row" and sets the outer array to the title of the row title, then loops through each sibling of type data and sets the individual properties for that inner array accordingly.

```js
$('#test').click(function(){
    var content = {};
    $('.Row_Title').each(function() {
      var row = $(this).text();      
      content[row] = {};
      $(this).siblings(".Data").each(function() {       
        var id = $(this).attr('id').split('~');
        blah = id[0];
        var html = $(this).html();
        content[row][blah] = html;        
      });
    })
    var hey = JSON.stringify(content);
    console.log(hey);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="Row_Title">Title 1</td>
    <td class="Data" id="Field1~1">Field1Value1</td>
    <td class="Data" id="Field2~1">Field2Value1</td>
  <tr>
    <td class="Row_Title">Title 2</td>
    <td class="Data" id="Field1~2">Field1Value2</td>
    <td class="Data" id="Field2~2">Field2Value2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="test">
Go
</button>
```

Comment: Wow awesome stephen, I'm gonna start workin with this right now. And yeah, they're empty but they are contenteditable and I'm having the user enter stuff into them.

Comment: I think this is going to work, awesome thank you so much.